# Expression must have a pointer to object type in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to use pointers in functions and arrays and when I call the report function in main, I keep getting an error Expression must have a pointer to object type. I have tried everything. Nothing seem to be working. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Please note: without the `report` function, if I call the other functions separately in `main` it works. It's not working only with the `report` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void print(int *list, int row_count, int column_count);
void rowaverage(int *list, int row_count, int column_count);
void allaverage(int *list, int row_count, int column_count);
void largest(int *list, int row_count, int column_count);
void report(int *list, int row_count, int column_count);

int main()
{
  int i = 1, row, column;
  int list[3][5];
  printf("Enter 3 sets of 5 integers::\n");
  for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
  {
    printf("Elements in the %d set are ::\n", row);
    for (column = 0; column < 5; column++)
    {
      printf("Element No. %d is ", i++);
      scanf("%d", &list[row][column]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    i = 1;
  }
  printf("The elements in array are:\n");

  report(&list[0][0], row, column);

  getch();
  return 0;
}

void print(int *list, int row_count, int column_count)
{
  int column, row;
  for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++)
  {
    for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++)
    {
      printf("%8d", *(list + row * column_count + column));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void rowaverage(int *list, int row_count, int column_count)
{
  int column, row;
  for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++)
  {
    float sum = 0, count = 0;
    for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++)
    {
      sum += *(list + row * column_count + column);
      count++;
    }
    printf("Average of row %d is %.2f\n", row, (sum / count));
  }
}

void allaverage(int *list, int row_count, int column_count)
{
  int column, row;
  float sum = 0, count = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++)
  {
    for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++)
    {
      sum += *(list + row * column_count + column);
      count++;
    }
  }
  printf("Average of all elements in array is %.2f\n", (sum / count));
}

void largest(int *list, int row_count, int column_count)
{
  int column = 0, row = 0;
  int largest = *(list + row * column_count + column);
  for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++)
  {
    for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++)
    {
      if (largest < *(list + row * column_count + column))
      {
        largest = *(list + row * column_count + column);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("The largest number in the array is %d\n", largest);
}

void report(int *list, int row_count, int column_count)
{
  int row = 0, column = 0;
  print(list[0][0], row, column);
  printf("\n");
  rowaverage(list[0][0], row, column);
  printf("\n");
  allaverage(list[0][0], row, column);
  printf("\n");
  largest(list[0][0], row, column);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your application to narrow down the place where error appears?

Comment: yes, error appears in the report function.

Comment: `<conio.h>` – are you on MS-DOS?

Comment: @Spook he has a compilation error.

Comment: @anansharm Can you maybe share the error message with us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In report function remove that line and see below report function:

```
int row = 0, column = 0;
```

In functions, use list as

```
int list[][5]
```

Call list as

```
list
```

not as

```
list[0][0]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(int list[][5], int row_count, int column_count)
{
    int column, row;

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++)
            printf("%8d", list[row][column]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void rowaverage(int list[][5], int row_count, int column_count)
{
    int column, row;

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {
        float sum = 0, count = 0;
        for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++) {
            sum += list[row][column];
            count++;
        }
        printf("Average of row %d is %.2f\n", row, (sum / count));
    }
}

void allaverage(int list[][5], int row_count, int column_count)
{
    int column, row;
    float sum = 0, count = 0;

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++) {
            sum += list[row][column];
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Average of all elements in array is %.2f\n", (sum / count));
}

void largest(int list[][5], int row_count, int column_count)
{
    int column = 0, row = 0;
    int largest = list[0][0];

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++) {
            if (largest < list[row][column]) {
                largest = list[row][column];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The largest number in the array is %d\n", largest);
}

void report(int list[][5], int row_count, int column_count)
{
    print(list, row_count, column_count);
    printf("\n");
    rowaverage(list, row_count, column_count);
    printf("\n");
    allaverage(list, row_count, column_count);
    printf("\n");
    largest(list, row_count, column_count);
}


int main()
{
    int i = 1, row, column;
    int list[3][5];

    printf("Enter 3 sets of 5 integers::\n");

    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        printf("Elements in the %d set are ::\n", row);
        for (column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
            printf("Element No. %d is ", i++);
            scanf("%d", &list[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        i = 1;
    }

    printf("The elements in array are:\n");

    report(list, row, column);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How will i solve this with pointers and arrays?? i actually wanted to solve it with pointers on functions and arrays.

Comment: You are using static array.So you must provide array width on functions. For dynamic allocated arrays, you can use pointer (as int **list) for functions.

Comment: You can also follow those links:

 - http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function

Answer (score 0):

So you're a passing a pointer to int in report function:

```
int list[3][5];
report(&list[0][0], row, column);
...
void report(int *list, int row_count, int column_count)
...
```

But then you are using list in report function as pointer to pointer to int:

```
list[0][0]
```

But it is not a pointer to pointer to int. It just has a type of int*. So "list" is dereferenced twicely in report functions. That's wrong.

You can fix it if you use just "list" as parameter in function calls in report() without "[0][0]":

```
rowaverage(list, row, column);
```

Comment: @RolandIllig Pointer to the first element of matrix is passed to report(). Then it is dereferenced in it twicely in original. It is a crash. But if it is dereferenced only once it will be the first element of the matrix. Why it wouldn't work?

Comment: @RolandIllig I see what you are talking. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the parameter **list[0][0]** to **list**. 
As list is a pointer to int, but list[0][0] is just an int. Their type is different, and the first parameter in your functions, a pointer is needed. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your arrays totally wrong everywhere.

Forget `&` and forget `*` for the time being. You don't need any in this program.

Your `list` is an `int[3][5]`, not an `int*` and not anything else. Declare it as such in all functions.

```
void rowaverage(int list[3][5], ...
```

and so on. Access it in the function like this:

```
list[row][column]
```

not `list+row*column_count+column`

Pass the list to functions like this:

```
rowaverage(list, ...
```

not `rowaverage(&list[0][0], ....`,

I have no idea why you wrote `report` differently from all the other functions, but it doesn't matter because all the other functions are totally wrong too. If they are wirking, it's by sheer luck.

Pick up a good C book and read it.

Comment: i wanted to use pointers in functions and 2D arrays, i wanted to know how will i be able to solve it with pointers and arrays.

Comment: It's OK to write unusually complicated and/or suboptimal code as an exercise, but you should warn us about that beforehand so that we don't waste time trying to correct it.